# Usando random en python en output me da un número y el resto son solo 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Estoy programando algo donde yo determine un rango de números y me elija una cantidad de números que yo determine y escoja esa cantidad de números aleatorios, por ejemplo determinó un rango de números del 1 al 30 y quiero que saque 5 números aleatorios de ese rango el problema es que el output es: un número y el resto son sólo ceros, por ejemplo 5,0,0,0,0.

Aquí voy a poner el codigo y si me pueden ayudar a solucionarlo estaria muy bueno, Gracias

````
print('numero de inicio')
inicio = int(input())

print('numero final')
final = int(input())

sigue = 'si'

while sigue == 'si':

    def listaAleatorios(n):
        lista = [0]  * n
        for i in range(n):
            lista[i] = random.randint(inicio, final)
            return lista

    print("Ingrese cuantos numeros aleatorios queri sacar")
    n=int(input())
    aleatorios=listaAleatorios(n)
    print(aleatorios)

    print('vas a seguir ?')
    sigue = input()

    if sigue == 'no':
        break```


output: 


número de inicio

1

número final

10

Ingrese cuantos números aleatorios quieres sacar

4

[2, 0, 0, 0]

vas a seguir ?

si

Ingrese cuantos números aleatorios quieres sacar

2

[10, 0]

vas a seguir ?

no
````

Comment: Saca `return lista` del for, si no, seguirá retornando en la primera iteración, por eso sólo cambia el valor de la primera posición de la lista.

Comment: Cuando lo saco me da none

Comment: Acá lo corrí sin problemas, sólo tienes que ponerlo fuera del ciclo for, ya te digo a mí me funciona así

Comment: Quisiera mandarte la imagen que lo demuestra, pero no sé si pueda por esta vía

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias.

Comment: una pregunta, hay alguna manera de hacer que los números no se repitan?

Comment: Una solución podría ser declarar una variable antes del while que podría llamarse, por ejemplo: `numeros=range(inicio, final+1)`, luego antes del for crear otra variable como esta: `elementos= random.sample(numeros, n)` y cambiar dentro del for `lista[i] = elementos[i]`. Sólo puedes introducir una n que no sea mayor que final ni negativa, si no te mostrará un error como este: `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que

```
   for i in range(n):
        lista[i] = random.randint(inicio, final)
        return lista
```

retorna de inmediato al ejecutar la primera iteración. Tienes que completar el `for` y luego retornar:

```
   for i in range(n):
        lista[i] = random.randint(inicio, final)
   return lista
```